# Contradictory answer by using equation of restitution

Tags: homework-and-exercises, angular-momentum, momentum, energy-conservation, angular-velocity

> A small disc and a thin uniform rod of length $l$, whose mass is $\eta$ times greater than the mass of the disc, lie on  a smooth horizontal plane. The disc is set in motion, in horizontal direction and perpendicular to the rod, with velocity $\vec{v}$, after which it elastically collides with the end of the rod. Find the velocity of the disc and the angula velocity of the rod after the collision. At what value of $\eta$ will the velocity of the disc after collision a) be equal to zero; b) reverse its direction?

If I conserve angular momentum, linear momentum, and use equation of restitution to get a third equation I get a different answer, and if I use conservation of energy rather then equation of restitution I get the correct answer, why so?

Comment: It would be great if you showed your calculations as well.